# how to use GWT map application id?

Tags: gwt

Since the app id is depending on the site name, how can i run it locally in dev mode?
I don't want to change the xml file every time and delete the key when debugging
Any solution for that?

many thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the official [Google Maps in GWT](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/MapsGettingStarted) project?  It should remove the need to do manual updates to your project, and should make it easy to run in dev mode.